# How to find out why my program is asking for a firewall exception?

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-firewall

We have a WCF service hosted in a WPF application. The WCF service uses the app.config file as a configuration source. The WCF service is only available to clients on the same machine, so it uses `NetNamedPipeBinding`

here is the relevant piece of config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <dataContractSerializer />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="NamedPipeBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:05" receiveTimeout="10:00:00"
      maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyService">

    <endpoint address="Facade" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NamedPipeBinding"
      name="NamedPipeEndpoint" contract="IMyService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/company/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/company/OtherService/API/" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NamedPipeBinding" contract="IOtherService" name="NamedPipeEndpoint" />
</client>
```

This all works great. Clients can talk to this server, and back around.
The problem is, that when deployed to client machine, it will ask for a firewall exception when it is first run: (similar to this one)

[image]

Since I am using named pipes, that shouldn't ask for the firewall exception.

So the question is actually: **How can I find out which part of the code is causing the Firewall Exception?** It is a big code base, and I tried searching for all terms related to TCP, HTTP, ... I also tried running *Fiddler* to try to find out more, but I don't see anything relevant.

Comment: That's really strange behavior, isn't it? You're using "localhost", but the behavior suggests the message is somehow being sent outside the machine, to a router, and back to the machine again on a port that's covered by a firewall. I'd wonder if there's some kind of MS policy in effect that even localhost requests are sent through a router? Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: According to this: http://superuser.com/questions/462443/what-are-reasons-for-local-windows-named-pipes-to-fail, windows firewall can block named pipes even when they are only used for inter-process communication on the same machine.

Comment: thanks for the info. Maybe as added piece of info, the other service (to which this one is a client) is using the same setup, and doesn't have this problem. So I suspect something else is causing this. Hence the question "How can I find out which part of the code is causing the Firewall Exception?"

Comment: Attach debugger (WinDbg) to css.exe at the moment the FW popup is displayed. Look at the callstack.

Comment: this is not giving me a lot of useful information. thanks for the suggestion though...